# How to say "Is it worth a visit?"

Tags: translation, expressions

What's a natural way of saying "Is it worth a visit?" in Japanese? Something like 「訪れ価値がある？」?

Comment: Maybe you should revise your question to incorporate nuance. The phrasing you guess for the Japanese in your question is not grammatical.

Comment: There are so many missing variables. A "visit" to a tourist spot? Someone's house? A foreign city? What will you do there? See something? Meet somebody? Talk some business? What "worth" do you seek? Profit? Satisfaction? Knowledge? Because you can't expect one-to-one translation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say something like 行く意味ある？, 行った方がいい？, 行くべき？

Comment: That sounds grammatically correct but the nuance is not what I was looking for..

Comment: @DaniG2k: If you are asking whether it's worth visiting an attraction etc., these are pretty standard ways of saying it

Comment: @DaniG2k Hmm... it could literally be translated as 行く/行ってみる(だけの)価値/[値打]{ねう}ち(が)ある？or 訪れる(だけの)価値/値打ち(が)ある？etc., but EnnoShoji's sentences sound more natural to me... (or maybe it depends on the context, formality, etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how (un)natural it might sound, but what about かい／がい　(`甲斐`)?

> - {来訪, 訪問}のし甲斐がある
> - {訪ね、訪れ}甲斐
> - 甲斐のある{来訪, 訪問}

Comment: Yes I like this a lot more. Like 旅行のし甲斐がありますか？

Comment: Sounds too "translated".  Not the native speakers' natural word choice.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya:  Hence the part where I said, `I don't know how (un)natural it might sound`.

Answer (score 1):

Also

行ったら満足しますか？

Would I be satisfied if I go?

Answer (score 0):

> What's a natural way of saying "Is it worth a visit?" in Japanese? Something like 「訪れ価値がある？」?

見て[行って] おくべきですか？ should be one of the natural words to ask about it, though it seems to be seldom written on the net.

If 行く意味ありますか？ works, then 行く価値ありますか？ should also work or might sound better than the former, but both sound a little too disrespectful to the place to my native ears.